# Using "Select Expr" and "Stack" to Unpivot PySpark DataFrame doesn't produce expected results

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, stack, unpivot

I am trying to unpivot a PySpark DataFrame, but I don't get the correct results.

Sample dataset:

```
# Prepare Data
data = [("Spain", 101, 201, 301), \
        ("Taiwan", 102, 202, 302), \
        ("Italy", 103, 203, 303), \
        ("China", 104, 204, 304)
  ]
 
# Create DataFrame
columns= ["Country", "2018", "2019", "2020"]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data = data, schema = columns)
df.show(truncate=False)
```

[image]

Below is the commands I have tried:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

unpivotExpr = "stack(3, '2018', 2018, '2019', 2019, '2020', 2020) as (Year, CPI)"
unPivotDF = df.select("Country", F.expr(unpivotExpr))
unPivotDF.show()
```

And the results:

[image]

As you can see in the above image, value of column "CPI" is the same as column "Year" which is not expected. The expected result is below:

[image]

Value of column "CPI" is get from each row of the pivoted table for the corresponding country.

Any idea to solve this issue?

Comment: Updated the answer for stack. Pls check if it works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**UPDATE**

Your "stack" expression is correct - just that to work with numbers as column names (2018, 2019 etc.), enclose them in back-ticks:

```py
unpivotExpr = "stack(3, '2018', `2018`, '2019', `2019`, '2020', `2020`) as (Year, CPI)"
```

---

**ALTERNATE SOLUTION**

Create a map with key as column name and value as column value, and then explode the map:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df = df.withColumn("year_cpi_map", F.create_map( \
                                      F.lit("2018"), F.col("2018"), \
                                      F.lit("2019"), F.col("2019"), \
                                      F.lit("2020"), F.col("2020") \
        )) \
        .select("Country", F.explode("year_cpi_map").alias("Year", "CPI"))
```

Or to generalize:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
import itertools

df = df.withColumn("year_cpi_map", F.create_map(list(itertools.chain(*[(F.lit(c), F.col(c)) for c in df.columns if c != "Country"])))) \
       .select("Country", F.explode("year_cpi_map").alias("Year", "CPI"))
```

Output:

```
+-------+----+---+
|Country|Year|CPI|
+-------+----+---+
|Spain  |2018|101|
|Spain  |2019|201|
|Spain  |2020|301|
|Taiwan |2018|102|
|Taiwan |2019|202|
|Taiwan |2020|302|
|Italy  |2018|103|
|Italy  |2019|203|
|Italy  |2020|303|
|China  |2018|104|
|China  |2019|204|
|China  |2020|304|
+-------+----+---+
```

Comment: Your first solution, with enclosing the column names in back-tick, worked for me! Thanks!