# In pyspark dataframe, how to take values of a given list of columns and, for each column of that list, turn it into a row with that value?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pyspark

I would like to make the following operation to a table

input

```
year | Jan | Feb | Mar
1995 | 1.1 | 1.2 | 1.3
1996 | 2.1 | 2.2 | 2.3
1997 | 3.1 | 3.2 | 3.3
```

output

```
year_month | gain
1995,01    | 1.1 
1995,02    | 1.2 
1995,03    | 1.3 
1996,01    | 2.1 
1996,02    | 2.2 
1996,03    | 2.3 
1997,01    | 3.1 
1997,02    | 3.2 
1997,03    | 3.3
```

But I dont even know the name of this operation to begin with.
I would like to know

- the name of that operation
- how would I do that in pyspark (preferably), or pandas.

Comment: check https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.2.0/api/python/reference/pyspark.pandas/api/pyspark.pandas.DataFrame.melt.html

Comment: For native Pyspark operation, check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74779993/using-select-expr-and-stack-to-unpivot-pyspark-dataframe-doesnt-produce-exp

Answer (score 1):

Your DataFrame (df_1)

```
+----+---+---+---+
|year|Jan|Feb|Mar|
+----+---+---+---+
|1995|1.1|1.2|1.3|
|1996|2.1|2.2|2.3|
|1997|3.1|3.2|3.3|
+----+---+---+---+
```

Importing necessary packages

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, expr, concat, lit, from_unixtime, unix_timestamp
```

Try this

```
unpivot_expr = "stack(3, 'Jan', Jan, 'Feb', Feb, 'Mar', Mar) as (month,gain)"
df_2 = df_1.select("year", expr(unpivot_expr))

df_3 = df_2.withColumn("month", from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(col("month"),"MMM"), "MM"))

df_3.select(concat("year", lit(","), "month").alias("year_month"), "gain").show()
```

***Output***

```
+----------+----+
|year_month|gain|
+----------+----+
|   1995,01| 1.1|
|   1995,02| 1.2|
|   1995,03| 1.3|
|   1996,01| 2.1|
|   1996,02| 2.2|
|   1996,03| 2.3|
|   1997,01| 3.1|
|   1997,02| 3.2|
|   1997,03| 3.3|
+----------+----+
```